# Linked List : What exactly sth.next refers to?

Tags: singly-linked-list

I recently watch a series of LinkedList video on youtube, as you may see in the below picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWkJE.png)

The video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RwWsHePdr8&index=11&list=PL6Zs6LgrJj3tWQfE6HK4JaX3wN96yhkD3

No I want to delete the number 15 (position 3), so here is the code:

```
if(position ==1) {
                ListNode temp = head;
                head = head.next;
                temp.next = null;
                return temp;
                }else {
                    ListNode previous = head;
                    int count =1;
                    while(count < position -1) {
                        previous = previous.next;
                        count++;
                    }

                    ListNode current = previous.next;
                    previous.next = current.next;
                    current.next = null;
                    return current;
                }
```

I have one question really confusing me :  In the picture: ｜10｜＿｜--> | 8 | __ |
if I type:『head.next』, does it means 8 ? or it means the node space next to 10?

Because in the code I revealed, I can't understand that:  "why the last code is 『current.next = null; 』?"
I think 『current.next』 points to number 11 ??
If 『current.next』means the node next to 15,  should the  previous code『previous.next = current.next』be change to『previous.next = current.next.next』? Which means 『current.next.next』can refer to number 11

Thanks in advance!!

Update: Is the head.next and head.next.next means like this ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr3nb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word next points to next node, which consists of address (memory address in system) and of value (for example 15)

If you know that you need to delete node with value 15, you can iterate through array and bind pointer of this nodes "next" to node, that 15 is showing on

```
ListNode temp = head;
while (temp.next != null){
    if (temp.next.value == 15):
        ListNode nodeWithValue15 = temp.next;
        temp.next = nodeWithValue15.next;
        // after rebinding address to your previous node, you can delete node with value 15
        nodeWithValue15 = null;
    temp = temp.next;
```

[Here you can see what next.next does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojDXN.png)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! Just in case, (because I am afraid I misunderstand your explanation)  is the relationship of the LinkedList node that the first line you mention about "next points to next node" look like this picture I draw?  p.s. I can not find anywhere to add a image in comment space, so I add the picture on my question article (In the last line)   Many thanks!!

Comment: Yes! You've drawn picture correctly.
World next refers to whole node as you've correctly drawn here. 
But beware stacking words ".next.next.next...." on top of each other, because last node, hast value of "next" Null - so you may end up with null pointer exception, if you try to call property "next" of non existing node.
Have fun and keep learning :)